# React trying to call child (useRef) function in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a sub component that is generating and displaying a random number.
I'm trying to control it from the parent.
but the ref current is null.

How can I call a child function from a parent in a functional component
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-joliot-85yom

```
function App() {
  const child = useRef();
  const generate = () => child.current.generate();

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <br />
      <Child ref={child}></Child><br />
      <button onClick={generate}>regenerate from parent (Not working)</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props){
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const generate = () => setNumber(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
  return <div>{number} <br /> <button onClick={generate}>regenerate from child</button></div>;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why not pass `() => setNumber(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));` as generate from parent to child?

Comment: @HMR can you show the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-joliot-85yom ? thanks

Comment: Sure, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-moon-84gfh) is an example.

Comment: See console: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Answer (score 3):

You cant use ref property in functional component, but you could handle any ref object by yourself, just don't call it "ref", react doesn't like it.
Check my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-microservice-perjr)

Comment: Almost exactly what I needed :) ... now I can "expose" a method from child and call it from the parent using `{someRef}.current()`. Thanks :)